# Spacy divides sentences inconsistently

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm using Spacy and I'm having problems with how it splits sentences. For some reason, some sentences are split into two or tree parts instead of one so when I try to train a model with TensorFlow I get an error that the dimensions of the vectors do not match.

I have tried changing the tokeniser to the whitespace tokeniser as indicated in [this link](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#custom-tokenizer-example). So, my class looks like (with the Benepar component commented out):

```
class BeneparAnnotator(SyntaxAnnotator):
    class WhitespaceTokenizer:
        def __init__(self, vocab):
            self.vocab = vocab

        def __call__(self, text):
            words = text.split(" ")
            spaces = [True] * len(words)
            # Avoid zero-length tokens
            for i, word in enumerate(words):
                if word == "":
                    words[i] = " "
                    spaces[i] = False
            # Remove the final trailing space
            if words[-1] == " ":
                words = words[0:-1]
                spaces = spaces[0:-1]
            else:
                spaces[-1] = False

            return Doc(self.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)

    def __init__(self):
        self.nlp = spacy.load('en')
        # self.nlp.add_pipe(BeneparComponent("benepar_en2"))
        self.nlp.tokenizer = self.WhitespaceTokenizer(self.nlp.vocab)
        self.extract_arc_representation = False
   
    ... other stuff ...


def ... other stuff ...
```

Now, when parsing the sentences with:

```
def parse_sentences(nlp, captions: List[str]) -> List[Span]:

    parsed_sentences = []
    for caption in tqdm(captions, desc="Parsing sentences"):
        parsed_caption = nlp(caption)
        if len(list(parsed_caption.sents)) > 1:  # This if is for debug
            length = len(list(parsed_caption.sents))
            as_list = list(parsed_caption.sents)
            pass
        parsed_sentence = list(parsed_caption.sents)[0]
        parsed_sentences.append(parsed_sentence)

    return parsed_sentences
```

This way of getting the sentence is taken from [here](https://github.com/nikitakit/self-attentive-parser/tree/acl2019#usage-with-spacy), as I want to retrieve the sentences parsed with Benepar but as some of them are divided into several sentences, instead of getting the whole parsed sentence I get several parsed pieces of a sentence.

And for some reason, for some sentences they are divided in 2 or 3 parts:

- Example 1: a black sheep having just had it s haired shaved off

  It's divided in: [a black sheep, having just had it s haired shaved off]
- Example 2: street signs say s. 3rd av. and no left turn

  It's divided in: [street signs say s., 3rd av., and no left turn]
- Example 3: one turn way only sign in the middle of the road

  It's divided in: [one turn way, only sign in the middle of the road]
- Example 4: two cows standing in the grass in front of tree 's

  It's divided in: [two cows standing in the grass in front of tree, 's]
- Example 5: a derby car # 30 is seen cutting a corner with it s right door ajar

  It's divided in: [a derby car, # 30 is seen cutting a corner with it s right door ajar]

I have other sentences similar to *Example 1* and they are split correctly in only one sentence. For example:

a back sheep that is standing in the grass

It's divided in: [a back sheep that is standing in the grass]

So when I get the *sents* for one caption with `list(parsed_caption.sents)[0]` I'm getting the whole caption instead only a part of the caption.

Where is the problem?

----- Update to try to explain better my problem. -----

I have a list of sentences that I want to parse with Benepar and then use them as input in a tool to see if I get better results. Due to limitations of the tool's anaconda environment, I need to use the 2019 version which is the one that works on Python 3.6.

The problem I have is that some sentences are split and Benepar parses them as independent chunks (instead of the whole sentence together) and as I try to get them with `list(parsed_caption.sents)[0]` (as there should only be one element, the whole sentence) and I get only one chunk, when I run the experiments I get an error that the size of the original sentence and the parsed sentence don't match.

I have over 616K sentences for the training set. Most of them are parsed fine and not divided in chunks and if I do:

```
caption = list(parsed_caption.sents)[0]
```

and then:

```
caption._.parse_string
```

I have the entire parsed sentences from Benepar.

Let's say I have this sentence: `The time for action is now.`

My expected content in `list(parsed_caption.sents)[0]` should be:

```
[The time for action is now.]
```

So when I want to get the parsed sentence with `caption._.parse_string` I get:

```
(S (NP (NP (DT The) (NN time)) (PP (IN for) (NP (NN action)))) (VP (VBZ is) (ADVP (RB now))) (. .))
```

But the problem is that for some sentences they are divided like (for example):

```
[The time, for action is now.]
```

So if I try to get the sentence with `list(parsed_caption.sents)[0]` I will only get a chunk of the sentence parsed. I only expect 1 sentence, no more.

As a result of only getting *The time*, when I'm training the model and the sentence *The time for action is now.* is selected I get an error because the length of *The time for action is now.* and *The time* is not the same.

Comment: when you write split, you are looking on the tokenized words or the entity split?

Comment: @NirElbaz What I want to get is the sentence tokenised by Spacy to process it with Benepar. The problem is that Spacy tokenizes some sentences in several parts and then the sizes differ, as the original sentence is whole in one chunk but the one processed by Spacy is in several chunks and when I get it with list(parsed_caption.sents)[0] I'm not getting the whole sentence.

Comment: Note that a tokenizer splits text into words, and is not directly related to sentence splitting. Is it correct that your input is always a single sentence? If so then just... don't use `doc.sents`, just use the tokens. You can also disable the parser.

Comment: @polm23 yes that is correct. I want to parse each sentence individually with Benepar.

Comment: Then why are you using `doc.sents` at all?

Comment: @polm23 Because this is my first time using Spacy and I'm following this explanation https://github.com/nikitakit/self-attentive-parser/tree/acl2019#usage-with-spacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the solution to my needs.

Since tool [Berkeley Neural Parser](https://github.com/nikitakit/self-attentive-parser/tree/acl2019#usage) gives two options (NLTK and Spacy) I tried the NLTK option and managed to achieve my goal. Due to the limitations of the environment I have to use the 2019 version which supports Python 3.6.

With NLTK I only have to do:

```
import benepar

class BeneparAnnotator(SyntaxAnnotator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = benepar.Parser("benepar_en2")
        self.extract_arc_representation = False
....
```

And then:

```
for caption in tqdm(captions, desc="Parsing sentences"):
    parsed_caption = parser.parse(caption)
    tree_as_string = parsed_caption.pformat(margin=500, indent=0, nodesep='', parens='()', quotes=False)
    parsed_sentences.append(tree_as_string)
```

In `tree_as_string` you will get the parsed sentence:

```
(S (NP (DT a) (NN restaurant)) (VP (VBZ has) (NP (JJ modern) (JJ wooden) (NNS tables) (CC and) (NNS chairs))))
```

You will have to adjust the `margin` parameter to set the length of the phrase, because if the phrase is longer than the margin, pformat will split it into several lines with the `\n` character in this way (not exact, just to show an example):

```
(S\n (NP\n (DT a)\n (NN restaurant)) (VP\n (VBZ has) (NP\n (JJ modern) (JJ wooden) (NNS tables) (CC and) (NNS chairs))))
```

And in this case, all sentences are processed correctly and I can train models without differences in the length of the original label vector and the parsed vector, because now sentences that with Spacy were split into several parts are no longer split into several parts.

I hope this helps someone using the same version of the tool.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use customize tokenizer at your stage and for sure not to split whitespace , use spacy regular tokenizer :

```
        from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer 

        self.nlp = spacy.load("en")     
        self.nlp.tokenizer=Tokenizer(self.nlp.vocab)
```

if you want to see the tokens :

```
def _TokoniezData(self,sentence):
        self.doc = self.nlp(sentence)
        self._tokonized=[]
        for token in self.doc:           
             self._tokonized.append((token.text ,token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
                    token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop,token.head,token.left_edge,token.right_edge,token.ent_type_))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but using the regular tokeniser Spacy keeps splitting some phrases into several sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty confused about what you're trying to do here, but here is my understanding:

1. You have a list of documents in plain text. You know each one is one sentence.
2. You pass the sentence to benepar somehow to get that parse.
3. You want to also pass the spaCy tokens to Tensorflow. (I don't understand how/why but OK.)

Your problem is that benepar reliably returns one sentence but spaCy does not, and that causes dimension issues with Tensorflow.

If any of the above is wrong please correct me.

Assuming that's correct, the tokenizer is not related to your issue. It determines how a string is split into words, not how sentences are defined. (Having a different number of tokens could also cause dimension issues, but it sounds like that's not your problem.)

If you just want a list of tokens for a piece of text from spaCy, you can do this:

```
tokens = list(nlp(text))
```

That's it. You don't need to use the sentence iterator if you already know each piece of input should be one sentence.

Also I notice that the instructions you linked to are from an old version of the docs, and don't really work with the latest version of benepar. Using the latest version and [the current README](https://github.com/nikitakit/self-attentive-parser#usage-with-spacy-recommended) I was able to write the sample code below, which splits the input text into a single sentence without issue. (I do get a warning from torch but it seems to be some internal benepar thing.)

```
import benepar, spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
nlp.add_pipe("benepar", config={"model": "benepar_en3"})
doc = nlp("a black sheep having just had it s haired shaved off")

for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent)
    print(sent._.parse_string)
    print("---")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I have updated my question at the end with an example to try to explain it better, let me know if you understand it and it makes sense to you.

Comment: Thank you for your further explanation, but it still seems like you can just do `list(nlp(text))`. Does that not fit your needs?

Comment: I must say, that I am not fully understand your need,  but I don't understand what is going wrong , if you pass the sentence to what I wrote you , you will get the sentence split  into tokens , BTW- from my experience ,  it is much simpler to write a small parsers to split to sentence rather than user SPACY split

Comment: @NirElbaz yes, but I don't want the sentence in tokens. I want the output from Benepar with the sentence transformed.

Comment: @polm23 If I do list(nlp(text)) I get a list with the words of the sentence, that's not what I want. Also I can't access the method ._.parse_string of Benepar, which I can access in the doc.sents

Comment: @Aker666 which Benepar capabilities you want to use? from what I saw almost all of them exists out of the box in spacy

Comment: @NirElbaz I assume they want a constituency parser.

Comment: If you don't want a list of tokens then can't you just call `nlp(test)._.parse_string`?

Comment: @polm23 POS and DEPT exists also in spacy

Comment: @polm23 @NirElbaz I want to use a constituency parser to see if it offers any improvement. With the 2019 version I can't do `nlp(test)._.parse_string` becuase it raises `AttributeError: [E046] Can't retrieve unregistered extension attribute 'parse_string'. Did you forget to call the set_extension method?` as `._.parse_string` is only available on a Span or Token class. Maybe I should try with NLTK instad of Spacy.

Comment: You can turn a Doc into a Span with the same tokens using `doc[0:-1]`.